# Locality in Condensed Matter Lattice Model

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-order

What is a proper definition of locality in condensed matter lattice model? I emphasize "condensed matter" because there is no Lorentz symmetry or "speed of light". I think it is quite important because this constraint will rules out most nonlocal lattice Hamiltonians. First, let's say local Hilbert spaces are put both on vertices and edges of lattice, and notion of lattice may not be that regular. It could be a very random lattice.

Answer (score 2):

You're wondering when a Hamiltonian is comprised of 'local' interactions? For practical purposes this usually means nearest neighbor or next-nearest neighbor interactions. More generally you'd define the Hamiltonian to be a sum of terms each having some compact support; interactions decay very rapidly beyond this range.

Once you have that you can place upper bounds on the rate information propagates in the system. This constrains time evolution, correlation functions, etc. These sorts of things are known as Lieb-Robinson bounds. They're useful when rigorously addressing some issues like when is topological order stable.

See this review for more: http://arxiv.org/abs/1008.5137